# iMessage Clear History Without Rebooting

Tags: mac, applescript, messages

If I remove all chat.db files in ~/Library/Messages on my Mac, I have to restart the whole system, otherwise iMessage says "updating database..." without doing anything.

I think this is because not all message caches are cleared. Does anyone know how I can clear those caches manually without rebooting the whole system?

Comment: I've never attempted to clear them, but the messages are actually in `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iChat/Data/Library/Messages/Archive/`

Comment: even if I empty that it does not work

Comment: I have never even thought about trying this but I would imagine you need to restart the services that are behind iChat/Messages. I will leave that as an exercise in Macintosh Detective work for the OP.

Comment: How can i locate these services?